# Migrate dashboard goes to content dashboard

Tags: 7, migrations

I am clicking on "configure" under Modules > Migrate UI and it is just taking me to `admin/content`. According to the [migrate_d2d module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d), the migrate module should have a dashboard.

> Enabling the migrate_d2d_ui module will add an "Import from Drupal"
>   subtab to the Migrate dashboard

I made sure to give the admin user permissions to use the module and I cleared the caches.

I am using Drupal 7.50 on the site I am migrating data from and 7.54 on the new site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happened but I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling and then reinstalling migrate module.